# Обновление div по нажатию

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, href

Пытаюсь добиться того, чтобы содержимое `<div class="content">` обновлялось при нажатии на ссылку.

**Script**

```
$(function() {
    $('.sidebar a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    var linkLocation = this.href;
       $('.content').load(linkLocation);
       return false;
    });
});
```

**Html**

```
...
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="page1.html" > № 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="page2.html" > № 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="page3.html" > № 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="page4.html" > № 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="page5.html" > № 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="page6.html" > № 6</a></li>
    </ul>
...
</div></div>
```

Если привязать тегам `<a>` id и указывать, например, `$('#btn1')` то все работает. Но если указывать имя класса, то работает только первая ссылка! Это очень странно, на мой взгляд. В чем может быть ошибка? Возможно есть более качественный скрипт для моей задачи. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

> если указывать имя класса, то работает только первая ссылка

В чем это выражается?

```js
$(function() {
  $('.sidebar a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var linkLocation = this.href;
    console.log(linkLocation);
    //$('.content').load(linkLocation);
    //return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="page1.html"> № 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="page2.html"> № 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="page3.html"> № 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="page4.html"> № 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="page5.html"> № 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="page6.html"> № 6</a></li>
    </ul>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: извините, ошибку понял, просто page2.html page3.html и т.д. не было в директории, поэтому ничего и не менялось... Как-то глупо даже(